# i want to sort table column using second word in a string using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with three columns.

```
  select   contactname  phone

 radio       A B         1234
 radio       B A         1212
```

I want to sort the second column using the second letter ( in first row it is B and second row it is A)using jquery..Any solution for this....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY SUBSTRING(field, 2) DESC;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY SUBSTRING(field, 2) ASC;
```

Comment: I need jquery to sort option for this requirement